# How to get relation between words in a sentence using nlp

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to get the relation between words in a sentence. Like if I have a sentence:
"Remind me to leave work today at 12PM"

Here "Leave" and "work" has a relation which makes the word "Leave work" which is the name of the task.

But how can I do that? Is there any NLP trick? Please help me if you have any answer.

Comment: You need to be careful with terminology: the two words _leave_ and _work_ combine to form a _clause_ with a verb (_leave_) and a noun (_work_), which is the object of the verb/predicate _leave_. If you then look for "subject/verb/object relations", you might find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One easier way to approach this problem is dependency parsing. Here is an example with the NLP library [spaCy](https://spacy.io/).

```py
import spacy

# load nlp pipeline
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# process document: incl. tokenization, pos-tagging, dependency parsing, ...
doc = nlp('Remind me to leave work today at 12PM')

# access dependency relations
for tok in doc:
    print(tok.head, '--->', tok, tok.dep_, sep="\t")
```

**Dependency relations:**

```py
Remind   --->   Remind  ROOT
Remind   --->   me      dobj
leave    --->   to      aux
Remind   --->   leave   xcomp
leave    --->   work    dobj
leave    --->   today   npadvmod
leave    --->   at      prep
at       --->   12PM    pobj
```

This is equivalent to the tree below.

```py
from spacy import displacy

# in Jupyter Notebook
displacy.render(doc, style="dep", options={'compact': True, 'distance': 120})
```

[image: Dependency tree]

From here, you can try to come up with constraints to extract the information you need, like "look for tokens that are tagged as `VV` and have a `dobj` relation", but the details really depend on your intended application.